# url rewrite rules in htaccess with php mysql

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How write url rewrite rules given below links.

1. original url for match pages:

   ```
   http://www.cricmelive.tv/live/09876/barisal_bulls_vs_chittagong_vikings_t20
   ```

now needed url:

```
    http://www.cricmelive.tv/live/09876/barisal_bulls_vs_chittagong_vikings_t20
```

2. original url for Channel Catgry:

```
http://www.cricmelive.tv/live/category.php?id=1
```

now needed url as:

```
http://www.cricmelive.tv/live/sports
```

3. original url for Sports Catgry:

```
http://www.cricmelive.tv/live/index.php?catid=1
```

now needed url as :

```
http://www.cricmelive.tv/live/cricket
```

4. orignal url for Channel Pages:

```
http://www.cricmelive.tv/live/channel-page.php?cid=45
```

now needed as :

```
http://www.cricmelive.tv/live/espn-3-live-streaming
```

I am new in ur rewrite. I post it again. Help me, how write rewrite url code again original url

Comment: The first two link examples are equal (number 1).

Comment: Numbers  2, 3 and 4 are ambiguous.  They are of the same pattern.  So a rewrite rule would match them all.  How do you determine the difference?

Comment: how rewrite it @Progrock `http://localhost/live/index.php?catid=2` into `http://localhost/live/cricket`

Answer (score 0):

I see what you are trying to do but it doesn't work that way. The parameters in the querystring are used at the backend in the sql to find the relevant records in the db using `$_GET`.

`catid=45` does not directly translate to `cricket` - in the database perhaps `catid=1` probably is `cricket` but the webserver doesn't know this relationship so you would need to alter your sql query such that it used `cricket` as the parameter in the where clause rather than 1.

For example:

```
http://www.cricmelive.tv/live/1 

that could be expressed easily with a rewrite rule, such as:
RewriteRule ^live/([0-9]+)$ live/index.php?catid=$1 [NC,L]


select * from table where category='cricket'
RewriteRule ^live/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ live/index.php?category=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: how rewrite it `http://localhost/live/index.php?catid=2` into `http://localhost/live/cricket` @RamRaider

Comment: as you said before `RewriteRule ^live/([0-9]+)$ live/index.php?catid=$1 [NC,L]` its not working @RamRaider